# Weapon afire on fire lash

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, psionics

Regarding the [pyrokineticist](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/prestigeClasses/pyrokineticist.htm)’s *fire lash* from *Expanded Psionics Handbook*,

Can you use weapon afire on a fire lash and does the 2d6/4d6 stack with or replace the normal 1d8 damage?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/50607/8610)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2d6 or 4d6 fire damage from *weapon afire* is definitely a bonus, so it would be added to whatever the weapon’s damage is. See

> She deals an **extra** 2d6 points of fire damage.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

The real question is whether or not the fire lash is a “weapon.” It’s certainly *like* a weapon, being held in hand, making attack rolls in order to deal damage, being eligible for Weapon Focus *et al.*, and counting as a whip for feats. But *weapon afire* is not a feat.

Ultimately, you will have to ask your DM if the fire lash counts as a weapon for *weapon afire*. I would say it absolutely should and that it certainly seems intended to be, but the wording doesn’t quite come out and **say so**, so it’s worth asking your DM about.

(Please also note that pyrokineticist is an exceedingly weak class; you’re welcome to play one anyway but you should do so aware of what you’re getting into.)

Comment: The fire lash ability says "...you fashion a 15' long whip...", which might be interpreted as it being a whip for intents and purposes, regardless of what it is made of. See HeyICanChan's answer to https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/123106/how-much-like-a-whip-is-a-fire-lash?rq=1 We also allowed them to be used together in our campaigns.