# Can magical enhancement bonuses and weapon special abilities be added to a fire lash?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, class-feature, psionics

Can a [pyrokineticist's](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPyrokineticist.html#pyrokineticist) *fire lash* be made magical so that, for example, it's a *+1 shock fire lash*?

If so, can a pyrokineticist have multiple *fire lashes*, each of them different? (For example, can a pyrokineticist have a *+1 shock fire lash* and a *+2 keen fire lash* and choose which to use each time the *fire lash* ability's used?)

Comment: Related: [Weapon afire on fire lash](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123235/33707)

Comment: That’s also my question.

Comment: Indeed it is, and I understand they are different.My comment merely "links" the two questions, displaying them in the right side bar under linked. Chances are, people that are interested in one of the two questions may be interested in the other.

Comment: Far more closely related would be your other *fire lash* question, [How much like a whip is a fire lash?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123106/4563)

Comment: @AVeryLargeBear I disagree, and in fact suspect you misunderstand the follow-up question: the follow-up question isn’t asking whether or not you can create multiple *fire lashes* at a time, but rather asking whether or not it is possible to maintain multiple separate enhancement suites for *fire lashes*, allowing you to choose which to apply. It’s a question that makes absolutely no sense outside the context of this question as a whole.

Comment: That's fair. I was a little confused by the original set of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is going to depend entirely on how one answers [How much like a whip is a fire lash?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123106/4563)—at this point, there are two answers to that question, one which reads the various descriptions of the *fire lash* being a whip as meaning it’s like a whip in all ways, and another which reads the various explicit ways in which the *fire whip* is described as being like a whip, and infers that these are the only ways in which it is like a whip. Both approaches seem reasonable to me, but neither seems definitively like “*the* correct answer.”

If the *fire lash* is like a whip only in the listed ways, magical enhancement is not listed, so it doesn’t work. If the *fire lash* is like a whip in all ways, then whips can be enhanced and therefore so can the *fire lash* be.

However, your follow-up question kind of makes things moot: there is no suggestion in *Expanded Psionics Handbook* that you are summoning the same *fire lash* every time. To wit:

> The whip remains in existence as long as the pyrokineticist holds it,

means that if you stop holding it, it no longer exists—it’s gone, and so are any enhancements you paid to have put on it. Your *fire lash* isn’t a real, stable object that you’re just calling to your person and then sending back into storage when you’re done with it. It’s a construct of unstable energy that doesn’t exist at all except while you keep it together. You create a new one every time you need another.

So while maybe you *can* enhance a *fire lash*, that is a complete waste of time and money since those enhancements are going to disappear as soon as you stop holding it. Maybe if you don’t need to sleep, you can kinda-sorta maintain your grip on it at all times, or you could use a locked gauntlet to make it impossible to let go of, but sooner or later this is going to go poorly for you.

Houseruling the *fire lash* to allow you to add persistent enhancements to it, fluffed as maybe enhancing *you*, or *your ability to produce a fire lash*, seems entirely reasonable to me. Allowing multiple enhancement suites, so you could choose which one to create at a given time, also seems reasonable to me. In fact, both of these houserules would still fall far short of making the pyrokineticist a good class—the class is a pretty pure trap, and I strongly recommend against it.

Answer (score 4):

## A [*fire lash*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPyrokineticist.html#pyrokineticist-fire-lash) is *not* a [masterwork weapon](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#masterwork-weapons)

The issue isn't really with the [pyrokineticist](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPyrokineticist.html#pyrokineticist) maintaining her hold on the [*fire lash*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPyrokineticist.html#pyrokineticist-fire-lash) effect indefinitely—adventurers are a kooky and powerful lot, and if an adventurer gets it into her head that she wants to hold something in her hand forevermore, then, by Pelor, [she *will*](http://dndsrd.net/armor.html#locked-gauntlet) [find a way!](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#sovereign-glue) The issue is, instead, with adding magical enhancement bonuses and magic and psionic weapon special abilities to *any* weapon: "Only a masterwork weapon can become a magic [or psionic] weapon," says [Creating Magic Weapons](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsCreation.html#creating-magic-weapons) (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 285-6), and a *fire lash* effect just *isn't* a masterwork weapon and, for the typical pyrokineticist, never becomes one.

So, until the pyrokineticist can somehow make the *fire lash* effect masterwork, she's stuck with a regular ol' no-enhancement-bonus, no-magic-or-psionic-weapon-special-abilities *fire lash* effect.

Comment: Yes, but a Monk’s unarmed strikes aren’t masterwork either, but you can enchant _them_. Generally a weapon has to _be able to become masterwork_ to need to be masterwork in order to be enchanted.

Comment: @MrHiTech Uh, [no, you cannot enhance a monk’s unarmed strikes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56981/4563). HeyICanChan is absolutely right here.

Comment: @MrHiTech Whether or not a monk's unarmed strike can be made magical or masterwork is hotly debated. Please, [take that up with answers to this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56981/8610) If you want to reject this answer's premise, that's (*ahem*) cool, but the *DMG* really does say what I quoted in the answer.

Comment: @HeyICanChan What about if you had a homebrew feat that made your fire lash masterwork?

Comment: @MrHiTech To avoid that conversation, I'd recommend the GM instead create a feat that had a benefit saying that *Your* fire lash *can have applied to it magical enhancement bonuses and magic weapon special abilities as if it were a normal masterwork melee weapon. These magical enhancement bonuses and magic weapon special abilities are the same each time you create a* fire lash.